# Sentence prints too many times

Tags: python, string, split

```
def main():
    print('Assignment #4-1, Ayub Hussein, ayub.hussein13@gmail.com')
    for line in fileinput.input():
        words = line.split()
        for i in range(0,len(words)):
            sys.stdout.write(words[i]+', ')
        sys.stdout.write('\n')

main()
```

OUTPUT:
hello, this, is\n
hello, this, is\n
hello, this, is\n

Comment: getting rid of that extra comma at the end

Comment: Use `str.join`: `sys.stdout.write(', '.join(line.split()) + '\n')`

Comment: No need for the range part. use `for i in words`

Comment: the output is printing the sentence by the amount of words in the sentence, example the input read was "hello this is" there is 3 words in the sentence so the output prints 3 times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're splitting words by space and rejoining with a comma, you can use `str.join` to get a single string, which you can then write at once, without a loop.

```
for line in fileinput.input():
    sys.stdout.write('{}\n'.format(', '.join(line.split())))
```

Or,

```
for line in fileinput.input():
    sys.stdout.write(', '.join(line.split()) + '\n')
```

---

Here's a little demo -

```
In [15]: line = 'hello this is'

In [16]: ', '.join(line.split())
Out[16]: 'hello, this, is'
```

Comment: ok this worked but it is printing out the same sentence according the amount of words

Comment: example output:                                                                                        
hello this is                                                                                                
hello this is                                                                                                
hello this is

Comment: @yoobi If it worked, and if you have a different problem, you should open a new question. As presented, I've solved this question...

Comment: @yoobi Furthermore, I can't understand what the trouble is, and what you want based on what you've said.

Comment: @COLDSPEED the output is printing the sentence by the amount of words in the sentence, example the input read was "hello this is" there is 3 words in the sentence so the output prints 3 times

Comment: @yoobi I edited my answer, I hope it's clearer now. The inner loop is not needed at all, since `str.join` takes care of that.